# Load custom library when form contains special field type

Tags: 8, entities

I'm writing a custom field in Drupal 8. I added a custom library that contains js and css to my module. They will be loaded on forms. Now I need a way to load the library only when some special field is placed in the form.

How can I check if a form contains a field with field type X?

```
function rate_field_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   if(/*Check if form contains field with type X*/)
   {
      $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'rate_field/admin-star-field';
   }
}
```

Comment: why don't you add libraries in field widget type?

Comment: Didn't know that was possible. Can you share some example code?

Comment: You said write custom field in drupal 8? Did you saw example module? [field module example](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/field_example/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/ColorPickerWidget.php)

Comment: Tnx the example was helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addedsome values in the render array of the formElement method in my customWidget class.

```
'#attached' => array(
    'library' => array(
      'core/jquery',
      'rate_field/admin-star-field',
    ),
```

Comment: Yeah, always add #attached and #cache information as close to the actual render arrays that will depend on it, they will automatically bubble up and will be added to the page/right place